# Video is splitted into various nomedia files

Tags: media-player, media, video-processing, vlc, lg

I recently recorded a video which was playing on the LG smart TV by using a pen-drive. Now when i inserted the pen-drive into my laptop it is not containing the video files, rather than that it is just containing no media files which are having names ending with STR, IDX, PIF, DIF etc. How to tackle the issue and how to convert these files into a video file.